# How to disable Back button on second Bottom Sheet Dialog?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I am creating a MainActivity. This activity has a button to open a Fragment and the Fragment has a button to open a bottom sheet dialog.

When I am on the Fragment, I can press Back button to return to MainActivity. However, when I have already opened the Bottom Dialog, I want to disable the Back button so that user can not press Back button when the Bottom Dialog is showing. So how can I do this? Thank you.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends SdwBaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void startAction(View view){
    LoadCashTutorialScreen loadCashTutorialScreen = LoadCashTutorialScreen.newInstance();
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, loadCashTutorialScreen, "LoadCashTutorialScreen").addToBackStack("LoadCashTutorialScreen").commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
      super.onBackPressed()
      //do something so that the back button is disable when the Bottom Dialog is showing
}
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class LoadCashTutorialScreen extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = initView(inflater, container, R.layout.load_cash_tutorial_screen);
        Button startDialog = view.findViewById(R.id.dialogButton);
        startDialog.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
            MyBottomDialog dialog = new MyBottomDialog();
            dialog.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "BottomDialog");
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Dialog:

```
public class MyBottomDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    @Override
    public void setupDialog(@NonNull Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.load_cash_bottom_dialog, null);
        dialog.setContentView(contentView);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
}
```

Note: I used to write some methods on onBackPressed() to prevent dialog disappears, however, the dialog always disappear when pressing Back. After debugging, I realize that onBackPressed() is not reached when the bottom dialog is showing. I do not know why.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since your Bottom sheet is a `Fragment`, you have to listen it in a separate way. Use this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // ...
    setupBackPressListener()
}

private fun setupBackPressListener() {
    this.view?.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
    this.view?.requestFocus()
    this.view?.setOnKeyListener { _, keyCode, _ ->
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            // Do what you want to do on back press
            true
        } else
            false
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Comment: Any particular reason why this only works on onViewCreated()? I've tried it on other stages but to no avail.

Comment: @HankChan Yes, it has to do with the `Fragment` lifecycle. Unlike an `Activity`, the `Fragment` view is not available until `onViewCreated()` is called. In short, the view needs to be non-null when setting the listener. Have a go through of this section in the documentation for more details, hope it helps: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#fragment_created_and_view_initialized

Comment: Did not work. Device back button still closes the sheet.

Comment: This method does not work when you change the focus on the bottomsheet, for example with an edittext.

Answer (score 8):

This will override default onbackpress of bottom sheet fragment, So, if you add this to bottomsheet fragment and leave it empty nothing will happen when you press back button.

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return object : BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme) {
        override fun onBackPressed() {
            // Handle backpress in here
        }
    }
}
```